# On changing to "French" and moving from one screen to another. The English content is loading and then french content is getting loaded

Tags: google-translate

On changing to "French" and moving from one screen to another. The English content is loading and then french content is getting loaded

Using google translator

```
<div id="google_translate_element"></div><script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', includedLanguages: 'en,fr'}, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script><script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Google language transalete

Comment: you can use this simple tool in the backend:  https://github.com/nidhaloff/deep_translator

Comment: im using magento2